# Creating has_many/belongs_to with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to turn  Model.attribute into Attribute.models.

e.g. I currently have `Model.first.attribute => "string"` and I'd like to add `belongs_to :attributes` into the Model.rb, and then after creating Attribute.rb, add `has_many :models`

I've added a column into the Model table for :attribute_id, and I am trying to do something like

```
Model.each do |m|
  a = Attribute.find_or_create_by_name(m.attribute)
  m.update_attribute("attribute_id", a.id)
end
```

Is this the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: What's your database look like?

Comment: @joeshmo What do you mean? It's mysql. I'm just trying to turn one of the Model's string columns into it's own model with a has_many relationship to the original Model.

Comment: How do you do this in the "existing data" you refer to in the title?

Comment: @joeshmo as in use update_attribute on Model to assign the foreign key, rather than Attribute.model.create.  I don't want to re-create any records, just add the relationship between the two models.

Comment: Which one `has_many` of the other?  Does a `Model` have many `Attributes`? If so, you can't put the fk in `Model`. On a 1-to-1, you can pretty much choose which you want it in, but in a 1-to-many relationship, the table with the key matters.  It goes in the one that `belongs_to` the other.

Comment: @joeshmo Attribute has_many :models.  Model already exists, and has an attribute_id column. I'm trying to create Attribute from the Model.attribute column, then update Model.attribute_id with the newly created Attribute.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Model `has_many :attributes` (and Attribute `belongs_to :model`), then there should be a `model_id` in the Attribute model.

Then you could do

```
Model.all.each do |m|
  m.attributes.create!(:name => m.attribute) unless m.attributes.find_by_name(m.attribute)
end
```

**UPDATE**

What you did seems to be OK for me then. The only problem is you'd have a column `attribute` and another on named `attribute_id` with a `belongs_to` in Model . I don't know how ActiveRecord would react when you'd type Model.first.attribute.

Comment: I'm doing it the other way around. Model `belongs_to :attribute` and I need to create the Attribute record from the Model's attribute, and then assign the Model to the newly created Attribute record (which has the same name as the Model's attribute column) without creating a new instance of Model.